Is it possible to change a radioactive isotope into a non-radioactive isotope?
Would it be possible to change a radioactive isotope of an element to a non-radioactive isotope by removing or adding neutrons? Just curious about this.

Beta minus decay turns neutrons into protons, does that count?

Yes, it's possible, 2 examples among others:

neutron capture adds a neutron to the initial nucleus,
a nuclear reaction of type (n, 2n) removes a neutron from the initial nucleus,
thus 59Fe-radioactive (n, 2n) gives stable 58Fe.


Thank you, that's helpful!
